# LetsEncrypt adding new Cert without killing Service

Tags: ssl, port, lets-encrypt

I use Let's Encrypt for my HTTPS certificates and every time I add a new cert or update a existing one I must stop my HTTP server on port 80 and start the Let's Encrypt script.

I want to add new certs and update the old ones but without killing the service on port 80 (in my example Passanger).

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Try with Webroot or Manual mode http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html#manual and http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html#webroot

Comment: is your issue that the certs are locked while the server is running (& which server)?